# Issue with traversing through XML data - the VBScript way

Tags: xml, vbscript, traversal

Sample XML:

```
<cart subTotal="USD 3.50" >

    <item productSubTotal="3.50" >
        <pkProductItem>241</pkProductItem>
        <itemCode>23455-green-XL</itemCode>
        <itemName>my product ( green - XL-size )</itemName>
        <qty>1</qty>
        <itemUnitPrice>3.50</itemUnitPrice>
        <totalItemPrice>3.50</totalItemPrice>
    </item>

    <item productSubTotal="9.90" >
        <pkProductItem>123</pkProductItem>
        <itemCode>23455-green-XL</itemCode>
        <itemName>my product ( red - L-size )</itemName>
        <qty>1</qty>
        <itemUnitPrice>9.90</itemUnitPrice>
        <totalItemPrice>9.90</totalItemPrice>
        <options> </options>
    </item>

</cart>

<finalTotalValue>3.50</finalTotalValue>
```

`Dim myXML: myXML= <the full xml string above>`

Note: The XML data above IS generated by using string concatenation.
The above XML data IS NOT loaded from an XML file.

After generated, how to use ASP VBScript to traverse through to read the data back?

1. How to retrieve `<finalTotalValue>` ?

   ```
   Dim oXML, URI
   Set oXML = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument")
   oXML.loadXML(objXMLhttp.responseText)
   URI = oXML.selectSingleNode("//itemCode").text
   ```

This seems not to be working.

2. How to retrieve item(s) inside cart using for loop?
   Inside `<cart>` can have multiple items.
3. How to retrieve value inside the tag? E.g.: `<item productSubTotal="9.90" >`
   I want to get 9.90, by looping through products inside the cart XML.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp) should help.

To loop through the cart you can do something like this:

```
totalcost = 0
set Cart_node = oXML.getElementsByTagName("cart")
' Loop through the cart node
for each itemNodes in Cart_node(0).ChildNodes
    ' get the product sub total from each item node
    productSubTotal = itemNodes.getAttribute("productSubTotal")
    ' Loop through each item node
    for each item in itemNodes.ChildNodes
        ' if the node name is "totalItemPrice" add the value to the totalcost
        if item.nodeName = "totalItemPrice" Then
            totalcost = totalcost + item.Text
        end if
    Next
Next
' totalcost will be the total of all values in totalItemPrice nodes.
```

You can retrieve `finalTotalValue` like this:

```
set final = oXML.getElementsByTagName("finalTotalValue")
finalTotalValue = final(0).text
```